# Cordova / Javascript Copy Image from URL to Store in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm building offline capability for my mobile app. The app basically have a function to sync content from server via API. The app then store the API response into local storage ( Using `localStorage.setItem('key',response)` ).

The app will then get the images URL (from the response) and attempt to store these images with cordova-file-plugin.

I have sorted out most of the part, but i have no clue after much googling on how to copy and image (URL) and save it to `cordova.file.dataDirectory`.

If anyone have any pointer will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead build the function from scratch, try some plugins below

https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js/

https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-file-cache

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/). It is basically a wrapper about some of the official cordova plugins.

Compared to cordova-file-plugin it is much more convinient to use it. Example:

```
$cordovaFile.createFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "new_file.txt", true)
  .then(function (success) {
    // success
  }, function (error) {
    // error
});
```

In case that your unclear how to download files. Have a look at the [ngCordova File Transfer Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/)